Как в Domain-Driven Design(DDD) реализуется связь многие ко многим?
можно посмотреть пример тут, https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many#2-implementation-in-jpa-1 , есть какая то сущность например студент и есть курс, у студента может быть много курсов, но и на курс может быть записано множество студентов, но на каждый курс студент может записаться с разной ролью, например на одном c правом посещения, на другом - с оценкой или еще что-то. В DDD работаем с корнем агрегата и по нему ищем необходимые данные, но тут нужно работать как со студентами так и с курсами, то есть запрос может быть покажи сколько студентов записаны на этот курс, так и наоборот - на какие курсы записан этот студент. Как правильно реализовать согласно DDD ?
у меня пока идея сделать 2 агрегата, в одном корень менеджер , в другом курс и связь 1-М
student(id) -> assigment_course(id, student_id, course_id, role)
course(id) -> assigment_student(id, student_id, course_id, role)


раз у записи на курс есть какие то свои аттрибуты, то это уже не просто промежуточная таблица для связи, а полноценный объект (или энтити, я в DDD не силен). В этом случае, у вас не может быть запроса типа "дайте мне курсы для студента", а скорее должны быть "дайте мне все записи, куда записывался студент". Плюс, запись на курс по идее должна иметь какое то доп поля, типа дата записи на курс, кто записал, может какой то статус записи (условно, предварительная запись и согласованная / отмененная запись) и тд. Но это всё просто мои фнтазии, хз конечно если это вообще вам релевантно.
